# WinUI: How to change NavigationView.Header background color?

Tags: xaml, navigationview, winui-3

I have a `NavigationView` and would like to change the header background color:

[image: header background with arrow]

I have tried:

- Looking in `generic.xaml` for likely styles to override
- Using a HeaderTemplate

Here's my code:

```xaml
<NavigationView Background="Gray">
    <NavigationView.Header>
        <Border Background="Green">
            <TextBlock Text="Header"/>
        </Border>
    </NavigationView.Header>
    <Border Background="Orange">
        <TextBlock Text="Sweet content"/>
    </Border>
</NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to override the `NavigationViewContentBackground` theme resource:

```
<NavigationView Background="Gray">
    <NavigationView.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewContentBackground" Color="Red" />
    </NavigationView.Resources>
    <NavigationView.Header>
        <Border Background="Green">
            <TextBlock Text="Header"/>
        </Border>
    </NavigationView.Header>
    <Border Background="Orange">
        <TextBlock Text="Sweet content"/>
    </Border>
</NavigationView>
```

Comment: Fantastic! How did you find `NavigationViewContentBackground`? I don't see it in the [NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview?view=winui-3.0) documentation or in `generic.xaml`.